# Sum hierarchical values in table for Continent, countries and states

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

Cosider following structure for population.

```
Asia(100+50+150=300)
    > China (20+80=100)
        >   China_StateA (20)
        >   China_StateB (80)
    > KSA (10+40=50)
        >   KSA_StateA (10)
        >   KSA_StateB (40) 
    > India (70+80=150)
        >   India_StateA (70)
        >   India_StateB (80)   


Europe(50+15=65)
    > England (50)
        >   England_StateA (20)
        >   England_StateB (30)
    > Ireland (5+10=15)
        >   Ireland_StateA (5)
        >   Ireland_StateB (10)
```

If i have same structure in a single database table like following

```
Id  Type    Name    ParentId    Population
1   Continent   Asia    0   
2   Country China   1   
3   State   China_StateA    2   20
4   State   China_StateB    2   80
5   Country KSA 1   
6   State   KSA_StateA  5   10
7   State   KSA_StateB  5   40
8   Country India   1   
9   State   India_StateA    8   70
10  State   India_StateB    8   80
11  Continent   Europe  0   
12  Country England 11  
13  State   England_StateA  12  20
14  State   England_StateB  12  30
15  Country Ireland 11  
16  State   Ireland_StateA  15  5
17  State   Ireland_StateB  15  10
```

Then how can i write a sql query that will return population on each level. i.e. will sum up population of states to find population of country. 
Similarly will sum up population of countries to find population of continents.

Comment: I guess you associate the "State" entries with "Country" entries by the name. But, How do you associate the continent with the countries? By ordering the ID field? I think the simplest way to achieve what you want is through a function or a stored procedure and iterating over a cursor: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms180169(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Is there any way to find out which country belongs to which continent and which state belongs to which country? I mean some of us humans know that India is in Asia but the database doesn't.

Comment: Updated comment: Use [hierarchical queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb677191.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sum after continents, one approach is just to add a column continent

**Sum after continent is then**

```
SELECT sum(Population) FROM yourTable GROUP BY continent.
```

Another approach is something like this with a hardcoded list

**Sum after continents**

Just use `sum` and `group by` with `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with in and a hardcoded List. In my Case Germany,England should represent Europe.

```
SELECT sum(Population) FROM yourTable GROUP BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('Name','(.*)_?') IN ('England', 'Germany')
```

Comment: This solution will give him, the summary for countries, but not for continents.

Comment: @Rumpelstinsk Thanks a lot for the notice. Just to early in the morning. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using CTE

```
WITH CTE_TMP
AS
(
    SELECT  Id,[Type],Name,ParentId,[Population]
    FROM    MyTable
    WHERE   [Type]  =   'State'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  M.Id,M.[Type],M.Name,M.ParentId,ISNULL(C.[Population],0)
    FROM    MyTable M
    INNER JOIN CTE_TMP C ON M.Id = C.ParentId
)
SELECT Id,[Type],Name,ParentId,SUM([Population]) AS [Population] 
FROM CTE_TMP 
GROUP BY Id,[Type],Name,ParentId
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Nice. One small error: you've got a stray `;` at the very beginning of your statement.

Comment: Thank you  Frank Schmitt

Answer (score 0):

Kordi's solution will help you, if you want to get the data for a countries and continents in separate views or specific countries. But if you want the see all in a single view, and you only have 2 levels in your herarchy, you can use this query.

```
SELECT parent.Id
    parent.Name,
    parent.ParentId
    SUM(childs.Population)
FROM mytable parent
    INNER JOIN mytable childs ON parent.Id = childs.ParentId
WHERE parent.Type = 'Continent'
GroupBy parent.Id, parent.Name, parent.ParentId

UNION

SELECT parent.Id
    parent.Name,
    parent.ParentId
    SUM(childs.Population)
FROM mytable parent
    INNER JOIN mytable childs ON parent.Id = childs.ParentId
WHERE parent.Type = 'Country'
GroupBy parent.Id, parent.Name, parent.ParentId
```

NOTE: If you have more than 2 hierarchy levels, 2 workarounds to this query are, using XML PATH or cursors inside a store procedure or function.